# Annotated User Expression [dialogFlow]

Tags: annotations, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Just a quick question. I'm currently doing a project using dialogflow and in the past I've used that. Usually under "Training Phrases", there are 2 different annotations. One with "**@**" and the other with a huge " **" "** ". Now there isn't a  choice for you to choose "**@**". Does anyone knows how to call out the entity directly?

For eg. **@** @sys.any:orderFood

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at the bottom of https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/training-phrases page, Template mode has been deprecated now (the one starting with @ sign).
You have to use example mode only from now on.

If you want to use `@sys.any:orderFood`, simply write a keyword for that and annotate it with the correct entity. It will be same as using `@sys.any:orderFood`.

[image: orderFood]

Hope it helps.